# DataTable javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatable

I'm using datatable to sort a table but when I execute the program only the data stored in the table is executed; and unable to sort the table. I've tried it in html and it works but when it comes to a razor view unable to sort. I've added this to the bundleconfig.cs

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/table").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"));
```

**View**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#data-table').DataTable();
    });

</script>

<table id="data-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-lg-3 tablehead">Item Number</th>
        <th class="col-lg-3 tablehead">Description</th>
        <th class="col-lg-3 tablehead">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="col-lg-3 tabledata">@item.itemNumber</td>
            <td class="col-lg-3 tabledata">@item.description</td>
            <td class="col-lg-3 tabledata">@item.quantity</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

**EDIT**
After debugging recognized that I was getting an error here $('#data').DataTable();. Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'DataTable'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table id="data-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-lg-3 tablehead">Item Number</th>
        <th class="col-lg-3 tablehead">Description</th>
        <th class="col-lg-3 tablehead">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="col-lg-3 tabledata">@item.itemNumber</td>
            <td class="col-lg-3 tabledata">@item.description</td>
            <td class="col-lg-3 tabledata">@item.quantity</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#data-table').DataTable();
    });

</script>
```

You need to load the jquery library before the DataTables libary. You also missed the closing table tag. And I always initialize data tables after the DOM loads the table.

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tvcnqL6w/1/)

Comment: it is producing the samething and I have no clue what's going on. is it that I should have datatables.js in the script folder

Comment: View the source of the page, click on the hyper links pertaining to the javascript libraries and css files. Make sure they're actually available.

Comment: Oh wait, you missed the </table> tag lol. Updated the code to make it clear.

Comment: libraries and files are available

Comment: table tag is closed

Comment: Maybe try to clear your browser cache? I've had issues with JS files been cached and hosing everything up.

Comment: so a datatables.js is not needed in the script folder?

Comment: i'm getting an error here        $('#data').DataTable();. Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'DataTable'

Comment: Your script references are messed up. I would download all three locally and link to them directly in the code. It's just odd because you said you were able to access them. Also you gave your table the id of 'data-table' not  'data'.

Comment: running in firefox giving a type error and also it is loading this file .dataTables.min.css twice

Comment: can you help me with another question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894042/javascript-button-click-not-working-asp-net-mvc